# Ruby: finding file in directory

Tags: ruby, directory

How would I be able to make my program keep asking the user for a valid file name if the input they enter is not a valid file name? This is my current code:

```
print "What is the name of the input file that contains the list of students to be grouped: "
input_file = gets.chomp


if (File.exist?(input_file))
    puts "this is a valid file"
else 
    puts "this is not valid"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep asking the user to provide an input until your condition (file exists) is met, you will have to make use of a loop. There are various you could use, here is an example using [`until`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-until), starting from the code you've provided.

```rb
puts "What is the name of the input file that contains the list of students to be grouped: "
input_file = gets.chomp

until File.exist?(input_file)
  puts "this is not valid" 
  puts "What is the name of the input file that contains the list of students to be grouped: "
  input_file = gets.chomp
end

puts "this is a valid file"
```

or another version to keep your code a bit more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```rb
input_file = ''

until File.exist?(input_file)
  puts "What is the name of the input file that contains the list of students to be grouped: "
  input_file = gets.chomp
  puts "this is not valid" if !File.exist?(input_file)
end

puts "this is a valid file"
```